# Save Fragment at Activities switching

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use PullToRefreshGridView (it's like ScrollView) with infinite scroll in a Fragment. PullToRefreshGridView contains many ImageViews, images downloaded from the Internet. User's click on ImageView starts new activity with the detailed information about image. The problem is when the user press back key in the DetailedImageInfoActivity, PullToRefreshGridView starts reload all images and loses it's scroll position. How I can avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You should save all activity data you want to reuse when going back in the onSaveInstanceState() method and restore the data when the activity comes back to the foreground in the onCreate() method.